# How to hide the label (street,road,city) names and city in Bing map V8

Tags: bing, bing-maps

I just start to use the new version of Bing map V8.
I want to display a map without label.

On the older version of Bing Map. It's working easy with the option [**LabelOverlay**].

```
labelOverlay: Microsoft.Maps.LabelOverlay.hidden
```

Now on the versîon V8 it's not working any more. I can't believe Microsoft forget it. I find we should use [**showMapLabels**] here

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f175baf0-bb59-44d9-ac0f-89b7403b6cdd/bing-maps-v8-api-loadmodule?forum=bingmapsajax

My code , when i set the map

```
map.setOptions({
                credentials: '<%= ArcadiaSettings.BingMapsKey %>',
                showMapTypeSelector: false,
                enableSearchLogo: false,
                enableClickableLogo: false,
                showMapTypeSelector: false,
                showScalebar: false,
                showDashboard: false,
                disableUserInput: false,
                showMapLabels: false
            })
```

but nothing change.
Somebody can help me please ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does work in V8 if used when the map is loaded. There is a known bug that just cropped up in the past week when using this in the setView function. This will likely be fixed in the experimental branch later this week. I assure you Microsoft didn't forget this feature. I had used it a lot during the preview and it worked fine.

Using the experimental branch, here is an example of hiding the labels when viewing aerial imagery:

```
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
    credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key',
    mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.aerial
});
map.setView({ labelOverlay: Microsoft.Maps.LabelOverlay.hidden});
```

You could also set the labelOverlay when loading the map rather than using setView.

Here is an example of hiding road labels.

```
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
    credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key',
    allowHidingLabelsOfRoad: true
});
map.setView({ labelOverlay: Microsoft.Maps.LabelOverlay.hidden});
```

Comment: ok thank you, so, i will just wait and try to use the experimental branch each days ^^ till Microsoft will fix it. Thank you ;-)

Comment: The issue with setView has been resolved in the experimental branch and will be rolled into the main release branch near the end of July. You can hide the map labels when in aerial or when the map option to allow hiding road labels is enabled using this code: map.setView({ labelOverlay: Microsoft.Maps.LabelOverlay.hidden});

Comment: OK thank you, i use now this link http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?branch=Experimental  , but still change Nothing. i still can see all the label :'( . I post a screenshoot about the code i use and the result i can see in my description. Thank you

Comment: Is the map in aerial mode? By default you can only turn off the labels when viewing the aerial imagery. This has been the case in all versions of Bing Maps. In V8 we have added the option to hide the labels when displaying road maps, however you must set the allowHidingLabelsOfRoad property to true when loading the map.